# What is the rule for using "from the time"?

Tags: grammaticality

Example usage:

> From the time I was elected, it was 3 years.

Comment: Some further context might be useful here- are you describing your history (as you might in a CV for example) or simply trying to say "it's been three years since I was elected"?

Comment: Or are you saying something like "From the time I was elected, it was three years before I was able to take my seat"? That's awkward, but grammatical; the point is that the **event you are describing** needs to be stated (either explicitly as here, or implicitly in context). You haven't given any context in your question.

Comment: I'm sorry, this is actually the exact message, i'm trying to interpret this "11And from the time that the daily sacrifice shall be taken away, and the abomination that maketh desolate set up, there shall be a thousand two hundred and ninety days. "  my question is, using the phrase "from the time", is the 1290 days before or after the daily sacrifice shall be taken away?

Answer (score -2):

It seems pretty clear to me

"the daily sacrifice shall be taken away"  (seems in the future at the time of writing)

-->  1290 days

-->  something else will happen.

1290 is pretty close to "two years, a year and a half"  : 13 days different.  Any connection?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be related to the question asked, much less an answer to it. You should [take the tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) to help get started.

Comment: @Laurel It is relevant to the question -- the asker clarified in comment on the question.